# Op-Amp "Fast Integrator" Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator

I'm trying to understand this circuit taken off of this [application note](https://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/AN-31.pdf).

[image: LM101A Fast Integrator Circuit]

To get it out of the way, I'm familiar with the basic integrator circuit and its workings. What I'm having trouble with are the extra components R2 and C2.

I've done a Laplace nodal analysis and got the equations and transfer function, but that didn't help me much. I feel that R2 and C2 have a much more "practical" role in this circuit.

So my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of R2 and C2?
2. Does the C1 capacitor have any influence in the circuit besides compensation?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the transfer function you allegedly  have made?

Comment: If C1 was a "normal" compensation capacitor for this opamp, it would be connected to pins 1 and 8.

Comment: [Not at all](https://imgur.com/a/7a4hJ).

Comment: @τεκ Yeah, that's part of the question. I'm not completely sure about C1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LM101 is about as old as the UA741 but is externally compensated.   It has amazing but difficult properties.  I would not suggest you try it, unless you really like challenges.

It has a large signal gain of >50k at 100kHz with a +/-10Vpp output swing. This would be an equivalent GBW product of 5GHz more, than a thousand times greater, except for the complexities of external compensation and bias null adjustment.

I won't even attempt to explain, other than it must be done this way to make it stable and only applies to this chip.

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on R2 and C2?

Comment: From a Bode Analysis you could find it converts the OA into a 1st order LPF with RC=T=5us for phase margin compensation as opposed to internally compensated OA's with T<10ms and if GBW was 5e6 only gives you a gain of 50 at 100Khz instead of this one which still has high gain.

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Widlar has lots of fun with this? Or was the designer Gene Horni?

Comment: Widlar after quit for more $ and joined National https://books.google.ca/books?id=xYKGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=lm101+original+designer&source=bl&ots=jgbRY-wK7H&sig=-emqJPXUQk6FncJmeBbwgZ1ThKM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBuoWK4PTXAhUQ24MKHRh2BA4Q6AEIQjAH#v=onepage&q=lm101%20original%20designer&f=false